# having trouble referencing separate routes file with express-subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I'm trying to add a subdomain to an existing node app using Express 3.0 and [express-subdomain](https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain).

(I've added the subdomain to my hosts file and that's working fine.)

The current app has all the routes in a separate routes.js file in the same directory as the main file, and it's called like this:

```
var routes = require("./routes")
//other stuff
routes.routeList(app);
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways to use the

```
app.use(subdomain('test-developer', [router]));
```

syntax and I can't figure it out.

I've tried

```
var router = require("./routes.js");
app.use(subdomain('test-developer', router));
```

and I get an error like "The second parameter must be a function that handles fn(req, res, next) params."

here's some more of the code:

```
//the developerRoutes.js file
var express = require('express');

exports.developerRouteList = function(app) {

var devRouter = express.Router();

devRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hi!');
});

}
```

and from the main.js file:

```
var developerRoutes = require('./developerRoutes');
//...
var app = express();
app.use(subdomain('test-developer', developerRoutes.developerRouteList));
//force https with this: 
app.enable('trust proxy');

app.configure(function() {

  app.use(function (req, res, next){
    var hostname = ( req.headers.host.match(/:/g) ) ? req.headers.host.slice( 0, req.headers.host.indexOf(":") ) : req.headers.host 
    console.log(hostname)
    if ((hostname === 'localhost') || (hostname === 'test-developer.localhost') || req.secure) {
      // request was via https, so do no special handling
      next();
    } else {
      // request was via http, so redirect to https
      res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    session = require("./routes/includes/session.js");
    next();
  });
  app.use(express.static('./public'));

  
  app.use(app.router);  
});

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
multiLess.configure(__dirname + '/static/less/', parentDirectory + 'public/css/',['main.less'],0);

routes.routeList(app);
```

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

Comment: Can you post anything from the routes.js file? Like what it exports or returns?

Comment: oh sure -- it exports 
   "exports.routeList" and it requires a bunch of separate js files that are referenced by the routes, e.g. ("app.get('/', datafree.home);" so it requires "datafree.js"

Comment: Is `exports.routeList` an instance of `express.Router`? Based on the express-subdomain docs it looks like that's what the subdomain function expects when you call `subdomain()`, so that you would have `subdomain('test-developer', <instance of express.Router>)`

Comment: thanks! it's not ... when I add 
    var devRouter = express.Router();

  devRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hi!');
  });

to the main file, it gives me a "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"; when I add it to the required file, I still get the " The second parameter must be a function that handles fn(req, res, next) params." error :(

I've made sure var express = require('express') is in both files ...

Comment: Please post more of your code in your question. If you can, make the problem repeatable with the code you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author of express-subdomain

I've answered this question in a previous issue - see https://github.com/bmullan91/express-subdomain/issues/4. I should probably add that to the readme as there is still a few folk using v3.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your posted code, I would try the following steps:

1. In `developerRoutes.js`, `exports.developerRouteList = function(app)` should be `module.exports = devRouter`, and it should be after `var devRouter = express.Router()`. Unless you're putting multiple routers in `developerRoutes.js`, you don't need to make a sub-object named `developerRouteList` within the `module.exports` object. Also, it doesn't look like you're using the `app` instance you pass in to `developerRoutes.js` so it should be okay to change this.
2. In `main.js`, now you can try `app.use(subdomain('test-developer', developerRoutes));`

Comment: Thank you! I think this syntax only works for Express 4.x ... this app is still Express 3.4. Looks like I'll have to migrate it before the subdomain work can happen. (fun!)